# have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Olá, criei uma Activity de Entrada de Dados e outra de "Resultado", quando o evento do botão é ativado, para realizar os cálculo e abrir a activity Resultado, aparece o erro de que não foi declarada no manifest. Alguém pode ajudar?

**Meu Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uerj.normal">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Menu_Principal">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Entrada_Dados">
        <activity android:name=".Resultado" />
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Erro**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A Activity **Resultado** está na mesma *package* da **Menu_Principal**?

Comment: Desculpe a minha falta de conhecimento, mas poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Se Activity **Resultado** está na mesma "pasta" da **Menu_Principal**?

Comment: Sim, está sim. "uerj.normal"

Comment: Ali estão as classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A declaração da Activity **Resultado** está dentro de um par de tags `<activity></activity>`.

```
<activity android:name=".Entrada_Dados"> Falta um / antes de >
<activity android:name=".Resultado" />
</activity> Está a mais
```

Altere assim:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Menu_Principal">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Entrada_Dados"/>
    <activity android:name=".Resultado" />

</application>
```